# Bad postgres connections + query never finishes

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a python job that drops and creates a postgres table everyday. The table has roughly the same size everytime. The action takes around 12 minutes, but on some days, it takes many hours and never finishes.

When I check the connections in pgadmin, I see some in red:

[image]

When I kill these connections and restart the job, it works.
Note that I always use a context manager when interacting with the database, so no connections should be dangling.

What steps can I take to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Use truncate https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html

Comment: Thanks but it is the `CREATE TABLE` query that hangs, the `DROP TABLE` actually goes thru easily.

Comment: with truncate you have one  command and it is usually quick, but if you want tp do it every day maybe a event based solution will be better as you don't need any connection at all

Comment: 1) Add the actual code as text to your question 2) **Do not** images for textual data, copy and paste as text. 3) All you are showing is active connections, not what those connections are doing. Assuming this is coming from [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) show the `query` field. 4) What is shown in the Postgres log?